# Find the condition that one root of $ax^2+bx+c=0$ be the reciprocal of a root of $a_1x^2+b_1x+c_1=0$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

Find the condition that one root of $ax^2+bx+c=0$ be the reciprocal of a root of $a_1x^2+b_1x+c_1=0$.

My Attempt:

Let $x_1$ and $x_2$ be the roots of the equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$. Then,
$$x_1=\dfrac {-b+\sqrt {b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$
 $$x_2=\dfrac {-b-\sqrt {b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$
Again, Let $x'_1$ and $x'_2$ be the roots of $a_1x^2+b_1x+c_1=0$. Then,
$$x'_1=\dfrac {-b_1+\sqrt {{b_1}^2-4a_1c_1}}{2a_1}$$
$$x'_2=\dfrac {-b_2+\sqrt {{b_2}^2-4a_2c_2}}{2a_2}$$

How do I proceed further?

Comment: Hint: let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be the two roots of $a_1x^2+b_1x+c_1=0$. Do you know the formulas for the sum and product of roots? Can you find the sum and product of the new roots?

Comment: @KennyLau, If $\alpha $ and $\beta $ are the roots of $a_1x^2+b_1x+c_1=0$, 
$$\alpha +\beta =\dfrac {-b_1}{a_1}$$
$$\alpha.\beta =\dfrac {c_1}{a_1}$$.

Comment: Yes. Can you find the sum and product of the new roots?

Comment: @KennyLau, What does new roots mean?

Comment: Well, the roots of the equation you're trying to develop.

Comment: @KennyLau, I couldn't understand what are you trying to say?

Comment: Well, $\dfrac1\alpha$ and $\dfrac1\beta$.

Comment: What do you mean by "reciprocal of the roots"?  Do you mean "reciprocal of the *sum of* the roots"?  Or "reciprocal of the *product of* the roots"?  (It doesn't make sense to ask that a single number be the reciprocal of two different things.)

Comment: @mweiss, Please find the edited version.

Comment: Still not clear. Does the question say that both roots of the second equation are the reciprocals of the two roots of the first equation? Or does it say that _only one_ roots of the second equation is the reciprocal of one of the roots of the first equation (while the other root can be anything)?

Answer (score -1):

In general if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the roots of equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$, then,

Sum of the roots, $\alpha+\beta=-\dfrac{b}{a}$, and Multiplication of roots, $\alpha\beta=\dfrac{c}{a}$.

So, $\dfrac{\alpha+\beta}{\alpha\beta}=\dfrac{-b/a}{c/a}=\dfrac{-b}{c}\implies\dfrac{1}{\alpha}+\dfrac{1}{\beta}=\dfrac{-b}{c}$, and $\dfrac{1}{\alpha\beta}=\dfrac{a}{c}\ \hspace{20pt}\cdots(\text{i})$

Let, $\alpha_1$ and $\beta_1$ are the roots of equation $a_1x^2+b_1x+c_1=0$  such that $\alpha_1=\dfrac{1}{\alpha}$ and $\beta_1=\dfrac{1}{\beta}$, as they are reciprocal.

Now from (i) we can write that $\alpha_1+\beta_1=-\dfrac{b}{c}$ and $\alpha_1\beta_1=\dfrac{a}{c}$.

So the equation whose sum of roots is $=-\dfrac{b}{c}$ and multiplication of roots is $=\dfrac{a}{c}$ can be written as: $x^2-(\alpha_1+\beta_1)x+\alpha_1\beta_1=0\implies x^2+\dfrac{b}{c}x+\dfrac{a}{c}=0\implies cx^2+bx+a=0$. Now this final equation $cx^2+bx+a=0$ and $a_1x^2+b_1x+c_1=0$ are same.

So comparing we get, $\dfrac{a_1}{c}=\dfrac{b_1}{b}=\dfrac{c_1}{a}$.

Comment: The answer in book is $(ab-b_1c)(ab_1-bc_1)=(cc_1-aa_1)^2$?

Comment: This answer assumes that *both* roots are the reciprocals of the other ones, which is not what the question asked. Besides, even in that interpretation, the coefficients need only be proportional $a / c_1=b/b_1 = c/a_1$, not necessarily equal.

Comment: yes, I've fixed this and this condition $\dfrac{a_1}{c}=\dfrac{b_1}{b}=\dfrac{c_1}{a}$ satisfies your book's answer $(ab-b_1c)(ab_1-bc_1)=(cc_1-aa_1)^2$ @AlbertEinstein

Answer (score -1):

Hint: the reciprocal of a root of $a_1x^2+b_1x+c_1=0$ satisfies the equation $c_1x^2+b_1x+a_1=0\,$. Then the problem reduces to finding the condition for the two equations to have a common root:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
ax^2+bx+c &= 0 \\
c_1x^2+b_1x+a_1 &= 0
\end{align}
\end{cases}
$$

Multiplying the first equation by $a_1\,$, the second one by $c\,$, and subtracting the two in order to eliminate the constant term, then discarding the root $x=0$ which is not eligible, gives:

$$
x = \frac{b a_1 - b_1 c}{c c_1 - a a_1}
$$

Substituting this expression for $x$ in either equation gives the relation between the coefficients.

Comment: Wish the downvoter had left a comment why.